# Identifying the network namespace of an lxc container

Tags: lxc, lxc-docker

I would like to know the mechanism to identify the network namespace of an LXC container. Basically I am looking for a mechanism to move the interface from the network namespace of an LXC back to the main namespace whenever an LXC crashes. For this, I need the network namespace of the lxc to start with.

Comment: I think the namespace is the pid of the lxc-start process itself; I would recommend you have hook script to attach and detach the interface, if you find some issue in lxc code that fails to detach the interface;

Comment: No the namespace need not be same as the pid of the lxc-start process